# Loop to obtain two pieces of user input and save to a global list

Tags: python, oop, loops, raw-input

Firstly, I am new to Python so please go easy on me... Secondly, I've never used a forum before so if I paste too much code or don't give exactly what you need, forgive me, I shall try my best:

#### WHAT I NEED MY CODE TO DO:

I need my code to ask the user for an input called moduleName then after moduleName is entered I need it to ask the user for the grade for that specific module. After that is entered I need it to ask again for module then the grade until there are no more to enter where by the user will enter -1 into the module bit to end it. I also need each item to save to a global list I have created. So when I use teh function I have created to view the list it prints out all modules and grades.

#### MY CODE THUS FAR: (my global list is at top of code named students[])

```
def addStudent():
    print 
    print "Adding student..."
    student = Student()
    firstName = raw_input("Please enter the student's first name: ")
    lastName = raw_input("Please enter the student's last name: ")
    degree = raw_input("Please enter the name of the degree the student is studying: ")
    studentid = raw_input("Please enter the students ID number: ")
    age = raw_input("Please enter the students Age: ")
    **moduleName= 0
    while moduleName != "-1":
        moduleName = raw_input("Please enter module name: ")
        grade = raw_input ("Please enter students grade for " + moduleName+": ")
    students.append(student)**


    student.setFirstName(firstName) # Set this student's first name
    student.setLastName(lastName)
    student.setDegree(degree)# Set this student's last name
    student.setGrade(grade)
    student.setModuleName(moduleName)
    student.setStudentID(studentid)
    student.setAge(age)


    print "The student",firstName+' '+lastName,"ID number",studentid,"has been added to the system."
```

#### THE OUTPUT I GET:

I have now fixed the loop so it breaks correctly... the only problem I have now is that the moduleName and grade fields save to my global list but only save the last input (being -1) as opposed to the multiple inputs entered... so confused.
The problem may also lie within this function I have created:

```
def viewStudent():
    print "Printing all students in database : "

    for person in students:
            print "Printing details for: " + person.getFirstName()+" "+ person.getLastName()
            print "Age: " + person.getAge()
            print "Student ID: " + person.getStudentID()
            print "Degree: " + person.getDegree()
            print "Module: " + person.getModuleName()
            print "Grades: " + person.getGrade()
```

Again apologies I don't know what's needed on forums etc so go easy on me...
Thank in Advance! =D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest replacing the `while moduleName != "-1":` loop with a `while True:` loop, and then insert this code after asking for the module name:

```
if moduleName == '-1':
    break
```

This will break out of the while loop when you want it to.

Addressing your second question, the `append` function is in the `else` bit of the whole `while` loop. This means that it only works when the function breaks. You need to put this in the main `while` loop after you get the input, and get rid of the `else`.

Also, I don't see `student` defined anywhere - what is it meant to be?

Here's the code you want:

```
while True:
    moduleName = raw_input("Please enter module name: ")
    if moduleName == '-1':
        break
    grade = raw_input("Please enter students grade for " + moduleName+": ")
    students.append(student)
```

Comment: Oh thanks I shall try that... I have defined student further up in the code but didn't want to paste it all in as I've noticed some people get annoyed when people paste too much code in: i defined it further up as student = Student() ...

Comment: I see no reason to change the `while` condition as you suggested (except if you are paid per line).

Comment: @Hans the `while` checks the condition, then executes the whole block of code if it evaluates to `True`. So even if the user inputs `-1` for the module name, the loop demands that the grade be asked too. Changing the loop fixes that problem.

Comment: @Volatility When user enters "-1", the condition would evaluate as `False` and not `True`, hence the condition defined in `while` loop is perfect.

Comment: @theharshest then why is the OP having trouble with exiting straight after inputting `-1` for the module name?

Comment: @Volatility Probably because of `else` that is being used with `while`.

Comment: @theharshest try it without the `else` block - I assure you the problem still exists

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22108/discussion-between-volatility-and-theharshest)

Comment: I have pasted my entore function into the text above I have tried both suggestions but it still does the same. It wont break until -1 is entered into both module and grade fields and it only saves the last input from module and grades which is -1. I have noted that every other field saves though, but they are only single inputs as opposed to this mutliple one I am trying to do... Thanks for help anyways guys =D

Comment: @Volatility: you are right. There is a problem with the `while` and using a break will fix that. In my imagination the raw_input was both just before the beginning and just before the end of the loop.

Comment: maybe I am asking the wrong question: If I add break it still asks for grade until -1 is entered then it breaks and still only saves last input of -1 in each field. is it because moduleName and grade are on the same line as in module cannot override the raw_input asked for grade? is there a way to put grade within the module section instead? (That probably totally makes no sense) I AM STUMPED!

Comment: yeh I had a look and it does work if i only ask for one value it just doesn't seem to work having 2 separate raw_inputs :/

Comment: apologies.. it does work... but if you enter -1 for module it then asks you the question for grade and if you enter -1 for grade ot breaks so in essence it does in fact work but i need it to break as soon as -1 is entered for moduleName. it also isn't saving anything inputted only the last input which would be -1... maybe I need to just re-write the whole thing?! I'm thinking it might be completely wrong!

Comment: @Lauren could you post the offending piece of code - it should work unless there's a typo or something

Comment: okies I'm gna post the entire code for teh one function out of 4 I have defined (we have the whole "get" and "set" thing going on and I know a lot of people dont like this but we have to do it)...

Comment: I have edited in teh main bit up top so all code is tehre for my function addStudent.... The bit not working is this: moduleName= 0
    while moduleName != "-1":
        moduleName = raw_input("Please enter module name: ")
        grade = raw_input ("Please enter students grade for " + moduleName+": ")

        students.append(student)

Comment: @Lauren correct me if I'm wrong, but you haven't updated the code yet. Change the while loop to `while True:` and the `if` statement to the one I posted in between the two raw inputs.

Comment: it works... however, it is doing what i said and not executing until both fields have -1 . instead of adding all the students modules and corresponding grades it's just saving -1 to the global list :)

Comment: ah yes sorry apologies... i have updated as said.. so loop sorted and breaking correctly, the only problem now is that only the last values are saving in the global list for module and grade as opposed to all the multiple values entered (p.s THANKS!)

Comment: @Lauren put your appending in the main while loop, so what you need to do is just indent the `students.append(student)` one more tab (four spaces)

Comment: i tried that and it just saves everything to the global list multiple times and still only save module and grade as last input :S

Comment: This chat is getting a bit long... but i think the problem is your `Student()` function. I don't know what the actual function is, but try making the function return a *copy* of the strings, by using `mystr[:]`. If that doesn't work, then try posting the code for the `Student()` function. Also, you can get rid of the part of the `addStudent()` function that's not part of the problem - it's got nothing to do with the problem, and that'll clean things up a bit.

Comment: haha i was thinking the same! ive edited my question, and just trying diff things . looking now I cant remember why i even have student= Students() .. I'm just trying to save it all to my global list students[] ... fingers crossed i can do this! :) ... and muchos Thanks for the help :)

Comment: try instead of appending `student` or whatever, just do `students.extend([moduleName[:], grade[:]])` and it should work.

Comment: also, if you want nested lists, use `append` instead of `extend`

Comment: okies I shall try this now, fingers crossed! will that also append everything or just module and grade? and do i put that one you tuped within the loop?

Comment: it'll add just the module and grade, and yes, it goes within the while loop

Comment: I'm also thinking the problem may lie within my view students function.  which I have just added to the question (bet you wish you hadn't looked at this question now haha)!

Comment: Well it looked like a simple one at first... Didn't know how complex it was gonna get! But good to know you've finally fixed the problem.